# How to ensure certain format on property

Tags: validation, express, typescript, joi

I'm wondering if it's possible to describe a format, that an interface property should have. For example:

```
interface User {
  age?: number,
  name: string,
  birthdate: string    // should have format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
}
```

I read about [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) but it seems to only apply to classes, not interfaces.

I'm building an API with node/express and want to have input validation. So I'm considering [Celebrate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/celebrate) which can take [joi type Schema](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to validate input. But I would like to use TypeScript instead to define my Schema / view model... As you see I try to use an Interface to define how the input of a given end point should look like:

- age: number, optional
- name: string
- birthdate: string in format "YYYY-MM-DD"

Any hints and help much appreciated :)

Comment: [Regex-validated string types are still in discussion.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579)

Comment: Thanks let's hope it's added to the language then

Answer (score 0):

> Any hints and help much appreciated :)

First and foremost : you will have to write code for the validation. It will not happen magically.

Two approaches:

## Out of band validation

You use `validate(obj) => {errors?}`. You create a validate function that takes and object and tells you any errors if any. You can write such a function yourself quite easily.

## In band validation

Instead of `{birthdate:string}` you have something like `{birthdate:FieldState<string>}` where `FieldState` maintains  validations and errors for a particular field. This is approach taken by https://formstate.github.io/#/ but you can easily create something similar yourself.

## A note on validators

I like validators as simple `(value) => error?` (value to optional error) as they can be framework agnostic and used / reused to death. This is the validator used by formstate as well. Of course this is just my opinion and you can experiment with what suits *your needs*